# Set the background color of UITabBarItem

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there an easy way to set the background color of an individual UITabBarItem?

In my scenario, I would like to use a different image for each of my 2 barItems and then set the background of my 2 barItems to a different background color each- say red and green.

I am not looking to set the background color of the whole tabBar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set selected and unselected image.

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the images will have the colored background? My question was about getting an image (asset) with no background. And then after adding the image, adding a colored background to the section behind that image in the Tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that following is easy.

- To use a big separated background image.
- To superpose image and background color. (using UIGraphics)